# Google Cloud functions + SQL Broken Pipe error

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, broken-pipe

I have various Google Cloud functions which are writing and reading to a Cloud SQL database (MySQL). The processes work however when the functions happen to run at the same time I am getting a Broken pipe error. I am using SQLAlchemy with Python, MySQL and the processes are cloud functions and the db is a google cloud database.I have seen suggested solutions that involve setting timeout values to longer. I was wondering if this would be a good approach or if there is a better approach? Thanks for your help in advance.

Heres the SQL broken pipe error:

> (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))")
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)

Here are the MySQL timeout values:

```
show variables like '%timeout%';
+-------------------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                             | Value    |
+-------------------------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout                           | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout                    | 300      |
| have_statement_timeout                    | YES      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout               | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                  | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout                | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout                       | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout                         | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout                          | 30       |
| net_write_timeout                         | 60       |
| rpl_semi_sync_master_async_notify_timeout | 5000000  |
| rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout              | 3000     |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout                    | 31536000 |
| slave_net_timeout                         | 30       |
| wait_timeout                              | 28800    |
+-------------------------------------------+----------+
15 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you cache your connection, for performance, it's normal to lost the connection after a while. To prevent this, you have to [deal with disconnection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html?highlight=reconnect#dealing-with-disconnects).

In addition, because you are working with Cloud Functions, only one request can be handle in the same time on one instance (if you have 2 concurrent requests, you will have 2 instances). Thus, set your pool size to 1 to save resource on your database side (in case of huge parallelization)